# Is it able to use different mip levels of one image as render target and shader resource in one drawcall?

Tags: graphics, glsl, vulkan

I want to implement generating hierarchy depth buffer by shader. The `i+1` mip map of the depth buffer is generated by min-pooling of `i` mipmap.

Supposed, I have already generated a depth buffer image.

**What I tried**

`i+1` mipmap of the depth image is used as render target, and `i` mipmap of the depth image is used as the shader input. Then I implement the min-pooling in glsl shader.

However, I got the validation error:
[image]

Does it mean that the same texture can not be used as shader input and render target at the same time, even the texture views are created with different mipmap level?

Comment: "*the texture views are created with different mipmap level?*" According to the validation layer, they are not.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for your comment. So theoritically, different mip levels of one image can be used as render target and shader resource at the same time?

Comment: @NicolBolas You are right. I made a mistake which I pass the full mipmap texture view to shader. That is how the overlaps happen